# Time dependent Hamiltonians

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators, perturbation-theory

I'm studying time dependent perturbation theory on Reed-Simon book "Method of modern mathematical physics, II". If one considers an Hamiltonian of the form
$$H(t)=H_0+V(t)$$
the corresponding formal propagator is given by
$$U(t,s)=e^{-itH_0}\tilde{U}(t,s)e^{isH_0}\,,$$
where $\tilde{U}(t,s)$ is the propagator associated to $\tilde{V}
(t)=e^{iH_0t}V(t)e^{isH_0}$.
How to prove that if $t\to [H_0,V(t)]$ is strongly continuous, then $U(t,s)$ is the actual propagator for $H(t)$? Any suggestions?

Comment: Cross-posted from math.SE as [Time dependent perturbation theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348218/214353)